# gspread update_cells always return 502 with httpsession error

Tags: gspread

I am currently trying to overwrite and google spreadsheet with new data using gspread api (version `0.4.1`) with `sheet.update_cells` but it keeps giving me 502 with err msg as follows:

`The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.<p>Please try again in 30 seconds.  <ins>That’s all we know.`

It seems to be http session problem from the stacktrace:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/models.py", line 476, in update_cells
self.client.post_cells(self, ElementTree.tostring(feed))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/client.py", line 303, in post_cells
r = self.session.post(url, data, headers=headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 81, in post
return self.request('POST', url, data=data, headers=headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread/httpsession.py", line 67, in request
response = func(url, data=data, headers=request_headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 111, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 57, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
```

I did a little bit investigation but it seems that the answer sort of varies, so i think i should better just my version here.

The code snippet is really nothing special like something as follows:

```
    sheet = gspread.authorize(credentials).open_by_key(spreadsheet_key).worksheet(worksheet_title)
    if not sheet:
      return
    if not len(new_rows):
      return
    sheet.resize(len(new_rows), sheet.col_count)
    active_range = 'A1:{0}{1}'.format(last_col, len(new_rows))
    cell_list = sheet.range(active_range)
    k = 0
    for row in new_rows:
      for field in row:
        cell_list[k].value = field
        k+=1

    sheet.update_cells(cell_list)
```

where my `new_rows` are just the new cell value i want to overwrite the sheet with. I don't think it is an authentication issue, as the same code snippet used to work but somehow at some point it keeps giving the 502.

Comment: What is the size of `cell_list`?

Comment: @Burnash  around 350 - 400 at current but might potentially grow

Comment: I'd try to lower the cell count to see when the server starts failing. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: ahh actually i know it works for smaller cell list size, but however i really need to update the cell_list at this size, is there any way to get around with it?

Comment: The error is cryptic and indicates that something is wrong on the API server.   I'd try to figure out at what size it breaks and update cells in chunks of this size.